# Detect the text of a span among several

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to compare if the text of a `h2` element is equal to the text of a `span`. These texts will be dinamics, therefore, I need to test it when the page is loaded. If the text is equal I will add a class to only this `span`.

My html would be:

```
<h2> "Tomatoes" </h2>

<ul>
    <li> <span> Oranges </span> </li>
    <li> <span> Apples </span> </li>
    <li> <span> Tomatoes </span> </li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery would be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if(jQuery('h2').text() === jQuery('ul li span').text()){
      jQuery('ul li span').addClass('bold');
  }
});
```

Any idea? Actually jQuery('ul li span').text() returns every text span and I cannot compare the specific text of `h2` among all.

Comment: You need to loop and test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate and check the condition

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var h2 = $('h2').text().trim().slice(1, -1); //slice to remove the quotes
  $('ul li span').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim() == h2) {
      $(this).addClass('bold');
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2> "Tomatoes" </h2>

<ul>
  <li> <span> Oranges </span> </li>
  <li> <span> Apples </span> </li>
  <li> <span> Tomatoes </span> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var h2 = $('h2').text().trim().slice(1, -1);
  $('ul li span').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim() == h2) {
      $(this).addClass('bold');
      return false;
    }
});
```

This might help you out in this specific case

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` to achieve this:

```
var h2Text = $('h2').text().trim().replace(/"/g, '');
$('ul li span').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == h2Text;
}).addClass('bold');
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/6b4zs7r9/)